# Ubuntu Server 12.04 ISC-DHCP-Server not working using standard configuration

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dhcp, linux-networking, dhcp-server

I have been trying to configure the isc-dhcp-server package to assign ip addresses to devices connected to my eth1 adapter.

Current Configuration
interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.2.1
network 192.168.2.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.2.255
```

dhcpd.conf:

```
ddns-update-style none;
subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option domain-name "Network 1";
    option domain-name-servers 203.12.160.35, 203.12.160.36;
    option routers 192.168.2.254;
    default-lease-time 42300;
    max-lease-time 84600;
    range 192.168.2.100 192.168.2.200;
}
authoritative;
log-facility local7;
```

After rebooting the server and ensuring that the isc-dhcp-server is running I plug my Win7 machine into eth1, however it fails to identify the network and get the assigned values from the server.

The only thing I can think of that does not match the standard configuration is that I have 3 ethernet interfaces in total eth0, eth1, eth2 (I am only using eth0 & eth1 currently) and eth0 is connected to a seperate network.

Can anyone tell me why I cannot get the isc-dhcp-server package working?

UPDATE(/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server):

```
# Defaults for dhcp initscript
# sourced by /etc/init.d/dhcp
# installed at /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server by the maintainer scripts

#
# This is a POSIX shell fragment
#

# On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests?
#   Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
INTERFACES="eht1"
```

Comment: What do you have in the file `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`?

Comment: Updated the question with it.

Comment: Is the typo `eht1` part of it?

Comment: Yeah the type.... so silly of me to miss that. Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 1):

You may need the following line in your dhcpd.conf in the subnet block.

interface eth1;

This helps the dhcp server to bind and respond on this specific interface.